# why no shown some views in mvc asp?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

### why no shown some views in my MVC project ?

for example when I type http://localhost:2430/newss/Create It shows but I get error for type another addresses such as  http://localhost:2430/newss/Edit or Delete .
My view code is correct and no problem.
Gives the following error:
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

```
    @model MvcApplication17.Models.NEWS

 @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

   <h2>Edit</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>NEWS</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.NEWSID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InsertDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InsertDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InsertDate)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupingID, "Subjects")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("GroupingID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupingID)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
      }

<div>

      @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </div>

      @section Scripts {
      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   }
```

RouteConfig :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Controller Code :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(NEWS news)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(news).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.GroupingID = new SelectList(db.Subjectss, "GroupingID", "Farsi", news.GroupingID);
        return View(news);
    }
```

Comment: Post your `Route.config` and your controller. The view code is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are posting points to a problem with the link you're trying to reach.

Maybe you don't have a controller able to handle that url or maybe you have a routing issue.

Ok, try this in your Route.Config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //Route defined to manage /newss/Edit/news
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Edit",
        url: "newss/Edit/{news}",
        defaults: new { controller = "newss", action = "Edit", news = new NEWS() }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: As Chris states, view code is meaningless, we need to see your controller code and the route.config file

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, URLs do not correspond to the physical location of views. Rather, based on your route config, the URL maps to a particular action in a particular controller, and then, either based on convention of by explicit reference, a view is utilized.

In other words, if you're getting a 404 for that URL, that means there's either no matching route or there's no controller/action combo that maps to the route. It has nothing to do with what views you have where.